# Non authenticated API in WSO API Manager 1.9?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.9 version .I created many APIs and all working fine.As per the requirement now i need a non authenticated API.How to create in API manger ,any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an API, in the Manage tap, you can select No Authentication for an API resource, as shown below.[image: No-Auth-API]

Comment: But impossible to set ,some issue with GUI ,I have created by editing swagger