# Anonymous access to APIs using WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We're trying to make Salesforce send a message to one of our APIs through WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0. However, it seems that [Salesforce is unable to authenticate and recommends using IP-restrictions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm).

So, is it possible to allow an anonymous/unauthenticated user to use an API in API Manager? IP-restriction I can take care of with firewalls, I don't have to do that in API Manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non authenticated API in WSO API Manager 1.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283499/non-authenticated-api-in-wso-api-manager-1-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an API, in the Manage tap, you can select No Authentication for an API resource. Then you will be able to access the API resource without access token. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283499/non-authenticated-api-in-wso-api-manager-1-9) for the similar question.

Comment: Yup, that worked. It was unclear to me that that dropdown was controlling authentication.